# Why connected app always requesting old community login?

Tags: community, customer-community, lightning-community, community-builder, community-cloud

Through App manager I have created a new connected app for my third party applicatio. From communityA VF page as a link I'm launching a third party application and it's working fine as expected.
Now I have created new communityB and through same VF page link If I launch the same third party application it's not working instead asking me to login to old CommunityA.
I wonder why I need to login to old community in this case and what is blocking me.
Note: I have added the required profiles to Community Member section.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have checked client ID, Consumer key and URL using for OAuth from the third party application end and compared with Salesforce end. So got to know that they are referring to our old community URL instead new. So asked them to update a new domain URL in their end. So now whenever I launch third party application it is working fine without redirecting to old community.